# Laravel - Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to send an email from Gmail using Laravel from localhost. I'm getting this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com 
:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 
(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond.)
```

My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

What is the error? Do i need to change some setting in the server or firewall?

Comment: have you tried enabling app access in your google account?

Comment: yes!! I enable "Less secure app access" in Gmail account. Same error when I using mailtrap, mailgun for send email.

Answer (score 6):

In .env file try the following code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
mail_username=myusername@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: After changing .env file-
1. Stop project execution from command prompt, 
2. run php artisan cache:clear
3. And then check

Answer (score 4):

In **Localhost**, edit .env file and paste the following code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In **Server**, edit .env file and paste the following code:

Step 1:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Step 2:

In config/mail.php change the following code:

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'), 

TO

'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),
```

Note: Make sure to enable "Less secure app access" in Gmail account.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is not a solution..

Comment: The part where you enable "Less secure app access" in Gmail is what solved it for me. I left the MAIL_DRIVER as smtp - if you change it to sendmail, you are using your servers's sendmail program. To change that Gmail setting, go to your profile, settings, then search for that phrase and it will find it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all  check your network connectivity and firewall services that are in use.
use your private network for this.
don't use public network.
public network deny the connection.